# Get configuration flags of a compiled tcl

Tags: tcl

I've a compiled tcl version 8.4 and want to check if `--enable-threads` was set when it was compiled or not ?

or if there is any another way to get the list of all passed flags.
Thanks

Comment: In more recent versions of Tcl you can read the variable `tcl_platform(threaded)` to check this, but as far as I can see that was added after version 8.4, which is terribly old now.

Comment: @ColinMacleod It works in 8.4 too. I happened to have an old version on this system that I've not deleted yet, and it defines the variable. _But the variable is typically absent on non-threaded systems._ That's the tricky bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## IMPORTANT NOTE!
>
> Tcl 8.4 is out of long-term support. Absolutely no further changes will be forthcoming to it, *not even if a catastrophic security error is discovered;* if your issue isn't fixed by 8.4.20, you'll need to go to 8.5 or later. We don't know of any such security issues, but we aren't looking and won't fix them if they're found.
>
> Support here is only on a “because we feel nice” basis. You **should not** create new work based on 8.4.

The global array element `tcl_platform(threaded)` is defined and set to `1` when the currently-used Tcl library is built with thread support. This is true from at least Tcl 8.4 onwards. Here's how to reliably get a nice boolean value you can check:

```
set isThreaded [expr {
    [info exist tcl_platform(threaded)] && $tcl_platform(threaded)
}]
```

**NB:** Some platforms are virtually always threaded anyway (because of how they work internally; this is the case with Windows and OSX if I remember right). Future versions of Tcl (8.7 onwards) will default to threaded everywhere; this will be the only supported build mode from 9.0 on. You'll still need the Thread package to work with threads in your script, but that's a standard extension these days.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 8.5 ([TIP 59](https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/59.md)), one can retrieve details about the build configuration using `tcl::pkgconfig`:

```
% tcl::pkgconfig get threaded
1
```

Note that this is not available in Tcl 8.4; if available, one does not have to protect against requesting an inexistent array entry `tcl_platform(threaded)`.